# Python - requests library

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to POST a request to an API using the requests libaray.

```
data = '{"DoorId": 6612642, "RelayFunction": {"RelayId": "Relay1", "RelayAction": "TimedOpen", "RelayOpenTime": 7000}, "LedFlash": 3}'

r = requests.post(url = Paxton_open_door, headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/json','Authorization':'Bearer ' + token}, data = data)
```

Insted of the values ( 6612642, Relay1, TimedOpen, 7000 and 3) I want to use variables, but I cannot get this to work?

Hope someone can help me out here?

Answer (score 0):

It's a pretty straight forward task to accomplish.

First you may define your variables:

```
door_id = 48848 # some value you may want to set
relay_id = "custom relay id"
relay_open_time = 10020 # your custom time
```

Then you can use them inside your `data` dictionary that is fed in the POST query:

```
data = '{"DoorId": door_id, "RelayFunction": {"RelayId": relay_id, "RelayAction": "TimedOpen", "RelayOpenTime": relay_open_time}, "LedFlash": 3}'

r = requests.post(url = Paxton_open_door, headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/json','Authorization':'Bearer ' + token}, data = data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to S0!

Hope this helps.

You can use variables like this

```
import json

door_id = 48848
relay_id = "relay id"
relay_open_time = 10020

# below is a dict
data = { "DoorId": door_id,
         "RelayFunction":{
                   "RelayId": relay_id,
                   "RelayAction": "TimedOpen",
                   "RelayOpenTime": relay_open_time},
         "LedFlash": 3}

# convert this dict to string for the post request
data = json.loads(data)


# your post request
r = requests.post(
         url=Paxton_open_door,
         headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/json','Authorization':'Bearer ' + token},
         data=data)
```

To learn more about `JSON` module - https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_json.asp

Comment: I needed to convert using json.dump

Now I got it working - Thanks alot :)